# Not able to found where the error is in my code?

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

Hi i am writing a spider in scrapy framework based on python language. The following code which i am trying but it is giving me an unexpected indent i didnt find anything like that. I entirely new this is my first spider in python. Please help me

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from first_sample.items import FirstSampleItem

class FirstSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "first"
    allowed_domains = ["reviews42.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.reviews42.com/mobiles/category/"]


    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        apps = hxs.select("//*[@id=\"col1\"]/div[@class=\"clear left summary-block relative\"]")
        count = 0
        items = []

    for app in apps:
        item = FirstSampleItem()
        item['title'] = appa.select("//div[@class=\"padding10 relative\"]/div[@class=\"thin-heading font700 black marginTop5\"]/a/text()")[count].extract()
        items.append(item)
        count += 1
    return items
```

IndentationError: unindent doesnt match any outer indentation level

Comment: If anything you should be getting a `'return' outside function`. Are you mixing tabs with spaces?

Comment: I am new to python i dont what it is traceback

Comment: @Venkat The error message.

Comment: I am updating the code and error message. Please check in few seconds

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Please check now code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop and the `return` statement in the `parse` function are not properly indented.

---

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    apps = hxs.select("//*[@id=\"col1\"]/div[@class=\"clear left summary-block relative\"]")
    count = 0
    items = []

    for app in apps:

        item = FirstSampleItem()
        item['title'] = appa.select("//div[@class=\"padding10 relative\"]/div[@class=\"thin-heading font700 black marginTop5\"]/a/text()")[count].extract()

        items.append(item)
        count += 1

    return items
```

Be careful to not mix space and tab when programming Python. Tab is a *single* character, and is not the same as a single space.

Comment: But that wouldn't raise an unexpected indentation error, would it?

Comment: @Haidro Well the Python parser expects the `for` statement to be at the same indentation as the previous statement, but it isn't. So it's an indentation error.

Comment: can you repost what it should look perfectly, i tried all my ways still showing

Comment: @Venkat It's very obvious in your question, but I added it anyway.

Comment: Hey i tried your code now another error coming saying that Syntaxerror:return outside function

Comment: @Venkat Because the `return` statement should be indented properly as well. You really should check the settings of your editor if you can't see it, as you might mix space and tab.

Comment: @Venkat Use `python -tt filename.py` to check if you're mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: i edited in pythonwin editer but still it's giving me error saying tat return outside function